# Dragon Age: Inquisition Import Save File

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

I keep on hearing about this Dragon Age Keep, but I actually have trouble using it and kinda lazy to select all of my choices again...I'm planning to get myself Dragon Age: Inquisition, but before that I need to confirm if it's possible to do the traditional import save? I still have Dragon Age Origins and Dragon Age 2 installed and completed with the save file on my PC. I be using the same one for Dragon Age: Inquisition. Is using Dragon Keep a 'must' in order to import save or it is just an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

If you log-in to Dragon Age Keep your savegames will be noticed and imported in the keep.
You can manage several different world states in the Keep like savegames.
If you start Dragon Age Inquisition without you've ever log-into the keep you'll get a pre-defined world state (which seems to be the same all the time)

[image]

Comment: So...it is not possible for me to import my save files from inside the game itself? I "have" to use Dragon Age Keep in order to import the save file then?

Comment: I dont know for pc Version but its not possible on console